# How to actually measure a T-Top on an IROC-Z

Tags: chevrolet, seal, camaro

When GM built the 3rd Gen Camaro, they installed T-Tops in some of them. Others they contracted out to another company to have them installed. The problem is, the T-Tops the contracted company installed were a different size than the GM installed ones. This is important if you want to replace the seals around the T-Tops to keep it from leaking. All of the places you turn to tell you the two different sizes and say you need to measure to figure out which ones were installed in your car. They don't really explain very well *what exactly to measure*. So, my question is: **What exactly to I need to measure and what measurement am I looking for to confirm one installation or the other?**

NOTE: Bonus points if you can post pictures of exactly what/how to measure.

Vehicle: 1986 Camaro IROC-Z 305cu TPI

Comment: When they talk about measuring from the center t bar I'd imagine it would be measuring to the outer edge? In this post the poster has a 82 but i'd imagine it would be the same process http://www.thirdgen.org/forums/members-camaros/580324-my-1982-camaro-z28.html#post4649180

Comment: Found on a page. Some 82-92 Camaros and Firebirds were converted to t-top cars after they left the factory by a company called Cars and Concepts (C&C). These aftermarket t-tops are not interchangeable with the stock ones and require different weatherstripping. To determine which top style you have, remove one of the tops and measure the side that tucks into the center support section of the roof. Factory, or Fisher, tops will be 30 1/4" while the C&C tops will only be 28" long. We do NOT stock or carry the replacement C&C weatherstripping.

Comment: I've also seen mention that with the fisher t tops that the door key will work on the t tops lock. And the C&C t tops have a separate key. And that C&C t tops have a black felt strip along the front and rear of the opening.

Comment: and, The easiest way to quickly identify which type you have is to measure the t-top glass length where the glass fits under the center t-bar: Factory Installed T-Tops (Fisher) = 30 1/4"  &  Aftermarket Installed T-Tops (Cars & Concepts) = 28", might make more sense.

Comment: @Ben - Why don't you put all of that into an answer along with a small diagram to describe what you're saying and call it a day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The easiest way to quickly identify which type you have is to measure
>   the t-top glass length where the glass fits under the center t-bar:
>   Factory Installed T-Tops (Fisher) = 30 1/4" & Aftermarket Installed
>   T-Tops (Cars & Concepts) = 28"

Both C&C and Fisher T-tops are installed in the same place relative to the rear of the roof. Due to the C&C T-tops being shorter the gap between the T-tops and windshield is larger. There will also be trim hiding the weld marks on the front and rear of the T-tops.
[image]